# Sql Reporting Services 2019 can't create or modify Datasource after installation

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reporting-services-2016

I'm doing a fairly vanilla install of Sql Reporting Services 2019 on a VM with the Reporting database being created on a Sql 2019 cluster server.

The service account is running as an Active Directory Domain user account following the instructions at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/install-windows/configure-the-report-server-service-account-ssrs-configuration-manager?view=sql-server-ver16.

I'm able to create a Report and view it, but I can't create or edit a datasource.

This is the error that happens when I attempt to create a datasource:
[image]

An error has occurred.
Something went wrong. Please try again later.

All the form elements are the page are disabled.

The Chrome developer tool shows a 500 error when this happens on this request:
/reports/api/v2.0/Extensions?$filter=ExtensionType+eq+(cast(%27Data%27,%20%27Model.ExtensionType%27))

The logs on the Sql Reporting Services shows this exception:

OData exception occurred: System.Net.WebException: The request failed with HTTP status 503: Service Unavailable.
at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SetConnectionProtocol()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.SoapMethodWrapper`1.ExecuteMethod(Boolean setConnectionProtocol)
at Microsoft.SqlServer.ReportingServices2010.RSConnection2010.ListExtensions(String extensionType)

I'm able to edit and update the DataSource using the PowerShell tools at: https://github.com/Microsoft/ReportingServicesTools  , so it appears to be a problem with the WebUI for Reporting Services.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling with different user accounts, but keep running into the same problem. Has anyone run into this before?

Comment: Does it work in IE/Edge?  Also, does the error message come up right when you click new data source, or do you have to click the Create button at the bottom to get the error to happen?

Comment: Have you resolve this issue? I have the same issue. configured two server back to back, one has this error, the second reported no problem. credential and os should be the same.